# How to test @Cacheable works with jmockit and spring-test

Tags: spring, caching, junit, jmockit, spring-test

I'm writing an integration test for application code with `@Cacheable` annotation.

Application is `@Autowired` and test is run by spring-test `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner`.

Proxy implementation is default – JDK. Jmockit is mocking framework.

**I would like to spy my userDao invocation count, to check if `@Cacheable` really works.**

Code under test

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
    @Autowired UserDao userDao;

    @Override
    @Cacheable(value="userCache", key="#id")
    @Transactional
    public User findById(long id) {
        User u = userDao.findById(id);
        /* <...> fill more user data */
        return u;
    }
}
```

Test code

```
import mockit.Injectable;
import mockit.NonStrictExpectations;

public class UserServiceImplTest {
    @Autowired UserService userService;
    @Injectable UserDao userDao;

    @Test
    public void findById_secondCallReturnsFromCache_doesntCallDatabase() {
        new NonStrictExpectations() {{
            userDao.findById(1); times = 1;
        }};

        userService.findById(1);
        userService.findById(1);
    }
}
```

However, test fails. Jmockit `@Injectable` `UserDao` is not injected to the spring context, so no invocations counted.

**Second try:** Replaced `@Autowired` `UserService` with `@Tested`, to get `@Injectable` working. Test fails, because `UserService` is an interface.

**Third try:** Replaced `@Autowired` `UserService` with `@Tested` `UserServiceImpl`. Test fails, because `@Cacheable` don't work (now `@Cacheable` annotation with JDK proxy mechanism cant work).

**How to fix or rewrite the test?**

Comment: Where are the annotations that enable SpringJUnit4ClassRunner (@RunWith) and configure spring context?